# Condition to display content if an entry has a relationship with another defined entry

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

I want to set a condition in a channel:entries loop whereby a chunk of content is displayed if the entry has a particular relationship with another particular entry. In other words, I want to say: "IF this entry has a relationship with entry 1, show X. IF this entry has a relationship with entry 2, show Y"...

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing your meaning, but this should work:

```
{relationship_field}
    {if relationship_field:entry_id == "1"}
        // Show X
    {/if}
    {if relationship_field:entry_id == "2"}
        // Show Y
    {/if}
{/relationship_field}
```

Note that this only accounts for parent-child relationships made within the entry you're currently viewing. To do the same for child-parent relationships, you'd need to do something similar with the [parents tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#id21).

Comment: Yes, I think this is doing exactly what I need. Simpler than I thought, thank you.